# Why in the editor the ui looks fine in size but when building the game and running it's not?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the gameview in the editor when the game is not running.
It looks the same when running the game in the editor.

[image: IN editor]

The rawimage size is set to W = 821 and H = 689
Same size of the texture render.

When running the game I'm choosing resolution 1920 x 1080 my highest resolution.
And graphics ultra.

This is a screenshot when running the game from the built file in full screen.
But the preview image not the same size on the height of the canvas in the editor it looks like it is the same height but after building and running it's not :

[image: After running the game from built file]

I want the preview image to be most to the right and cover the top and bottom edges only to keep the width as it is but when running from the built file the height and position not the same like in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using UI you should configure canvas scaler correctly, I configure it as the attached image and its work right for me.
but if you are using sprites you should calculate the scale of it by code, at first calculate width and height of the screen and then width and height of sprite(with sprite renderer componetn) and calculate it.
[Canvas scaler configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2xg6.png)

Comment: I guess I messed it up on my side with too many cameras under the canvas. What I want to do is to show a gameobject on a rawimage on the canvas.

Comment: This is a link for a question I did and deleted and undeleted now show my settings for the canvas and raimage. Maybe you have something like with a complete example ?

Comment: At first configure your canvas as I explained, then right click on canvas and under ui select Image, you can add as many Image as you want. for example one Image for your background and another for your spaceship gameobject :)